# Typeerror when pulling json data from Github

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, git, d3.js

I'm using d3.json to pull a json link from Enterprise GitHub (same repo/folder that the js file is in.

```
d3.json("https://raw.github.exampleEnterprise.com/path/to/repo/data.json?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",function(error, flare) {
  console.log(flare);
  root = flare;
  update(root);
});
```

And I'm getting the error `TypeError: flare is undefined`

When I pull it from a public GitHub, it all works fine

```
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/repo/data.json",function(error, flare) {
  console.log(flare);
  root = flare;
  update(root);
});
```

When I paste the enterprise link with token in the address bar of a browser, I can see the whole JSON file. So it's odd that it's not coming through, or why.

EDIT:
I've added an error return,

```
d3.json("https://raw.github.exampleEnterprise.com/path/to/repo/data.json?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",function(error, flare) {
  if(error){ console.log("There was an error", error); }
  console.log(flare);
  root = flare;
  update(root);
});
```

and can see that the error I'm receiving is:

There was an error XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }

EDIT 2: Looking in the Network tab, I saw a 200 response to my GET request. When checking the "Response" tab of the request I could see a red error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` I tried using d3.text() instead of d3.json(), which still returned "undefined" (as I could see in the console). So that explains that error.

Comment: Just a hunch, your url does not specify any protocol.  As default it might be using HTTP, and maybe Github does not like private repo's over HTTP, what if you do `https://exampleEnterprise.github.com/path/to.....`

Comment: good thought, unfortunately already doing so, though it wasn't clear. I've updated my question, thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong, but usually GitHub serves up files like this with the content type of `text/plain`. If you're function is expecting JSON but receiving back content of type text, it could be causing a problem...

Comment: @War10ck based on my EDIT 2 it looks like you may be on to something. Do you have a recommendation on how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

In that callback you are not checking if there is an error.

If there is an error, data will be undefined.

If you were to do something like this:

```
d3.json("__url__", function(error, data){
    if(error){ console.log("There was an error", error); }
    else{
        console.log("Here is your data: ", data);
    }
})
```

You can see if there is an error, and as long is there not one, then you can access the data object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there is an error, but I don't see any informative info from it. It looks like the json isn't returning.

Comment: Can you paste in the response of "console.log(error)" ?

Comment: I do above in my question under "error I'm receiving is"